# Google Guava loadAll to load cache partially

Tags: java, guava

I need to cache objects in bulk returned by a third party rest service. I was trying to explore CacheLoader.loadAll() API which works fine with getAll() only when all the objects not found in the cache can be fetched successfully. If I have a partial case where few of the objects are fetched and few are not fetched than this api contract throws 
    (loadAll failed to return a value for key)

I would like to know what is a better way to support the above use case using google guava.

```
        this.cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(1000).build(new CacheLoader<String, NamedEntity>() {

            @Override
            public Map<String, NamedEntity> loadAll(Iterable<? extends String> keys) throws Exception {

                Map<String, NamedEntity> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

                for (NamedEntity namedEntity : client.getNamedEntities(keys)) {
                    map.put(namedEntity.getYkId(), namedEntity);
                }

                return map;
            }
        });



        try {
            entities = cache.getAll(keys);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Guava cache's successor, [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine), allows for partial results from its `loadAll(keys)` method. In that case the `Map<K, V>` will not contain entries for missing keys.

Comment: Thanks Ben. I would also want to know whether writes to cache from multiple threads for the same <key,value> in Caffeine are thread safe.

Comment: Caffeine is thread-safe and has the same behavior as `ConcurrentHashMap`. If you wanted to mutate the value then you might do so under a `asMap().compute` method to block other writes to that key. However, like Guava, `loadAll` is non-blocking because it would require locking multiple entries, so it will replace if the entry was concurrently loaded. A blocking `loadAll` is supported by `AsyncLoadingCache` because it inserts `CompletableFuture` proxies to compute into.

Comment: Thanks Ben. I also wanted to know when is the StatsCounter.recordEviction() called? I was trying to gather the cache stats metrics & for that I have subclassed StatsCounter but I did not see the recordEviction() callback getting called upon the finish of the expiry interval set.

Comment: Guava and Caffeine both default to evicting when periodic maintenance is triggered, which occurs after a write or some reads (or manually by calling `cleanUp()`). Caffeine supports prompt notification if you use a `Scheduler` to provide a background thread. `recordEviction` is called when this maintenance occurs. Give it a try with an explicit `cleanUp` or scheduler and see if that works in your test.